# C++ & SDL Why does handling my objects directly rather than with pointers sometimes cause vissual problems?

Tags: c++, class, object, sdl, sdl-2

I'm currently developing a GUI application using C++ and SDL2. I've run into some very strange behavior when trying to render some of my textures. I'm using a custom Texture warper based on Lazy Foo's tutorials (http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/43_render_to_texture/index.php) called Texture, built on top of SDL's texture class SDL_Texture. Usually when I create a texture using my default constructor "Texture()", and then try to render it to the screen, everything works as intended. However on 3 separate occasions now I've gotten very strange behavior. In the problem cases it often draws a texture from a different object and it comes out distorted, sometime it simply doesn't draw at all, and often is is erratically flashing as if the renderer is only drawing it every few frames. When run multiple times the textures are always messed up, but which symptoms appear such as whether it flashes or even renders at all changes without recompiling the code. There are no compiler errors or warnings, and I get no stderr output while running. What's strange is if I set up the object as a pointer and instantiate it using "new Texture()" everything works exactly as it should.

Luckily I have found a solution to my problem using pointers, but I can imagine only one of three things is causing this: There is a bug in the SDL2 library (unlikely), there is a bug in my Texture class, or I am missing some very fundamental concept of how objects are handled in C++. In any of these cases it will come back to bite me if I try to ignore it.

I'm developing on Linux (Ubuntu 16.04) and compiling with G++.

I will include some code for one of the problem instances below. In this case I was creating a "HistoryEntry" class that could take some attributes and draw itself to an arbitrary X and Y. All of the HistoryEntry attribute Texture objects besides timeText are messed up and when they do draw they seem to draw a distorted version of timeText's texture. It almost looks like they kept their own width and height values but their texture got over written when I loaded timeText. However, from my understanding a constructor will always generate a completely new object and it's especially strange if only some of it's attributes get copied over. Everything runs smoothly if I change all of the attribute Texture objects to pointers that point to said Texture objects.

Texture constructor and load function:

```
Texture::Texture()
{
    //Initialize
    mTexture = NULL;
    mWidth = 0;
    mHeight = 0;
}

bool Texture::loadText( std::string textureText, SDL_Color textColor, TTF_Font* gFont)
{
    //Get rid of preexisting texture
    free();

    //Render text surface
    SDL_Surface* textSurface = TTF_RenderText_Blended( gFont, textureText.c_str(), textColor ); 
    if( textSurface == NULL )
    {
        printf( "Unable to render text surface! SDL_ttf Error: %s\n", TTF_GetError() );
    }
    else
    {
        //Create texture from surface pixels
        mTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface( getRenderer(), textSurface );
        if( mTexture == NULL )
        {
            printf( "Unable to create texture from rendered text! SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
        }
        else
        {
            //Get image dimensions
            mWidth = textSurface->w;
            mHeight = textSurface->h;
        }

        //Get rid of old surface
        SDL_FreeSurface( textSurface );
    }

    //Return success
    return mTexture != NULL;
}
```

Texture render method:

```
void Texture::render( int x, int y, int anchor, SDL_Rect* clip )
{
    SDL_Rect renderQuad;
    //Set rendering space and render to screen
    if(anchor == MIDDLE_CENTER){
        renderQuad = { x - mWidth/2, y - mHeight/2, mWidth, mHeight };
    }else if(anchor == MIDDLE_LEFT){
        renderQuad = { x, y - mHeight/2, mWidth, mHeight };
    }else if(anchor == MIDDLE_RIGHT){
        renderQuad = { x - mWidth, y - mHeight/2, mWidth, mHeight };
    }else{
        renderQuad = { x, y, mWidth, mHeight };
    }

    //Set clip rendering dimensions
    if( clip != NULL )
    {
        renderQuad.w = clip->w;
        renderQuad.h = clip->h;
    }

    //Render to screen
    SDL_RenderCopy( getRenderer(), mTexture, clip, &renderQuad );
}
```

HistoryEntry class:

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>
#include <string>
#include "auxx.h"
#include "texture.h"
#include "history_entry.h"

HistoryEntry::HistoryEntry(){

}

// Constructor for notifications
HistoryEntry::HistoryEntry(int t, std::string n, std::string v)
{
    //Atributes
    type = t;
    eventTime = GetTimer();
    name = Texture();
    name.loadText(n, defaultColor, defaultFont);
    value = Texture();
    value.loadText(v, defaultColor, defaultFont);
    //code = Texture();
    //code.loadText(c, defaultColor, defaultFontSmall);
    //icon = i;
    timeText = Texture();

}

// Constuctor for error and warnings
HistoryEntry::HistoryEntry(int t, std::string n, std::string c, Texture i)
{
    //Atributes
    type = t;
    eventTime = GetTimer();
    name = Texture();
    name.loadText(n, defaultColor, defaultFont);
    //value = Texture();
    //value.loadText(v, defaultColor, defaultFont);
    code = Texture();
    code.loadText(c, defaultColor, defaultFontSmall);
    icon = i;
    timeText = Texture();

}

void HistoryEntry::draw(SDL_Renderer* renderer, int x, int y){

    if(type == NOTIFICATION_ENTRY){
        name.render(x + 7, y + 15);
        value.render(x + 620, y + 15);

        // Set up time text
        // Seconds
        if(timeSince() < 60){
            timeBuff = std::to_string(timeSince()) + " sec ago";
            timeText.loadText(timeBuff , defaultColor, defaultFont);
        }
        // Minutes
        else{
            timeBuff = std::to_string(timeSince()/60) + " min ago";
            timeText.loadText(timeBuff , defaultColor, defaultFont);
        }

        timeText.render(x + 440, y + 15);
    }else{
        icon.render(x + 3, y + 13);
        name.render(x + 44, y + 15);
        code.render(x + 44, y + 45);
        //value.render(x + 620, y + 15);

        // Set up time text
        // Seconds
        if(timeSince() < 60){
            timeBuff = std::to_string(timeSince()) + " sec ago";
            timeText.loadText(timeBuff , defaultColor, defaultFont);
        }
        // Minutes
        else{
            timeBuff = std::to_string(timeSince()/60) + " min ago";
            timeText.loadText(timeBuff , defaultColor, defaultFont);
        }

        timeText.render(x + 440, y + 15);
    }
}

int HistoryEntry::getHeight(){
    if(type = NOTIFICATION_ENTRY){
        return 63;
    }else{
        return 89;
    }
}

int HistoryEntry::timeSince(){
    return GetTimePassedSeconds(eventTime);
}
```

Part of display function that calls the drawing:

```
void DrawGraphics()
{
    SDL_Renderer *renderer = getRenderer();

    //Clear screen
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor( renderer, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF );
    SDL_RenderClear( renderer );

    ...

    // Draw history if it is active
    if(history_active){
        historyBackground.render(480, 79);
    }

    // Y position of first history entry
    int rowY = 134;
    // Draw history entries
    if(history_active){
        // Set color for history lines
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 52, 64, 79, 0);

        for(int i = 0; i < history.size(); i++){
            history[i].draw(renderer, 495, rowY);
            // Increment the y value based on entry size
            if(history[i].type == NOTIFICATION_ENTRY){
                rowY += 63;
            }else{
                rowY += 89;
            }
            // Draw lines
            SDL_RenderDrawLine(renderer, 495, rowY - 1, 1287, rowY - 1);
        }
    }

    //Update screen
    SDL_RenderPresent( renderer );

}
```

Comment: You should start by reducing the code as much as possible. Remove anything that isn't truly needed, any wrapper classes. Put everything into a single file, etc. The goal is to create a minimal code that reproduces the problem, and that *we* can compile ourselves. Make sure that the code you'll provide is enough to reproduce, otherwise we won't be able to help. ([mcve])

Comment: You're right, I totally understand, my code snippets were too large and not compilable. I am having trouble intentionally reproducing the problem though, the whole issue is I don't understand how or why the problem is appearing. Changing seemingly unrelated code can make the problem go away or pop up somewhere else. I will mess with it tonight and try to get it to show up in the smallest amount of code possible.